# Add web chart part to page

Tags: sharepoint-server

I already created a list in which I added a content type. The list is for Research. There are different kinds of Research, so all of them will be placed in this list. Every Research type has its own chart. When the user is adding values in the form (list), the chart must be updated. I tried to add the web chart, but when I tried to connect it to the web part of the Research type, it says "Your page does not contain any Web Parts that are capable of providing data to your chart Web Part". How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

looks like your using the wrong webpart! the webpart your using is showing the error because you can only connect to a listviewwebpart to this webpart that I think is on the same page! you need to make sure you select the correct options!

just follow this tut:

first make sure you have the correct webpart!

> 1.Begin by either creating a page or by opening an existing page for editing.
>
> 2.On the ribbon, click the Insert tab, and then in the Web Parts group, click Web Parts.
>
> 3.In the Categories section, click Business Data.
>
> 4.In the Web Parts section, click Chart Web Part, and then click Add.

if you have the correct list than you can go to the following!

Phase 2: Connect to a data source and configure the Chart Web Part

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-chart-by-using-the-chart-web-part-HA101889211.aspx#_Toc276035255

> 1.Locate the Chart Web Part that you want to edit, and then click the Data & Appearance hypertext.
>
> 2.In the Data Connection & Chart Appearance Wizards page, click Connect Chart to Data to open the Data Connection Wizard.
>
> 3.In the Choose a Data Source page, select a data source type, and then click Next. chose connect to list
>
> 4.In the Connect to Data Source page, select the data source that you want to use, and then click Next.
>
> 5.In the Retrieve and Filter Data page, preview the data that will be used for the Chart Web Part.
>
> 6.To optionally configure parameters to display a subset of the data, use the following procedure:
>
> 1.Click the plus sign (+) next to Filters to expand the Define Filter Parameters section.
>
> 2.Use the Parameter Name list to select an item, such as a column in the data set.
>
> 3.Use the Type list to select an appropriate operator type.
>
> 4.Use the Default value box to specify the criterion that you want to use for the filter.
>
> 5.Click Preview Data to view the filtered data.
>
> 6.Repeat Steps 1-6 for each additional parameter that you want to use for the chart.
>
> 7.After you have finished previewing and filtering the data, click Next.
>
> 8.To optionally specify how you want the data to be displayed, use the Bind Chart to Data page. Do this by specifying one column for the Y
>   Field, and another column for the X Field.
>
> 9.Click Finish to view the chart in its page.